# UDP прием в Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, сеть

Хочу принимать пакеты UDP без Indy. 
Для этого использую модули Posix.ArpaInet, Posix.SysSocket.

```
var
  a: UInt32;
  p: UInt16;
  FSocket: integer;
  FSocketAddr: sockaddr; //sokraddr_in нет
begin
    FSocketAddr.sa_family:= AF_INET;
    a:= inet_addr(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IPaddr)));
    p:= htons(Port);
    FillChar(FSocketAddr.sa_data, SizeOf(FSocketAddr.sa_data), 0);
    move(a, FSocketAddr.sa_data[0], SizeOf(UInt32));
    move(p, FSocketAddr.sa_data[4], SizeOf(UInt16));
  //заполнил структуры (скорее всего не правильно)
    FSocket:= Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if FSocket > 0 then begin

      if Bind(FSocket, FSocketAddr, SizeOf(FSocketAddr)) = -1 then
      begin
      ....  
end;
```

Но bind = -1. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а что в `errno` (или как его аналог называется в delphi)? и сразу, какой адрес и порт указываешь `bind`'у?

Comment: ip:= '192.168.100.250'
port:= 5514
ошибка 99, если можно верить LastError

Comment: `99` — это `EADDRNOTAVAIL`... как минимум, ошибка в том, что в `sockaddr_in` сначала должен идти порт и только затем адрес... и покопайся в API — там должна быть отдельная структура для ip... если не заработает, то смотри, что возвращает `inet_addr`, попробуй вместо этого указать `0` (это соответствует `IF_ADDR_ANY`, `0.0.0.0`, т.е. слушать все интерфейсы). Также проверь, что `192.168.100.250` — это действительно адрес локального интерфейса (см. `ip addr`).

Comment: поменял местами, ошибка осталась. 
192.168.100.250 — это действительно адрес локального интерфейса

Comment: тяжело признаваться, но надо было файл сделать исполняемым и запустить не из под среды. PAServer по какой-то причине не запускает через себя